# Node.js/Express 4.0 POST Request Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm just starting out with node and could use a bit of direction for testing out POST requests with Postman.

```
router.route('/athletes')
.post(function(req, res) {

    var athlete = new Athlete();     
    athlete.name = req.body.name;  

    athlete.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Athlete created!' });
    });
 });
```

I wasn't having any issues with the GET requests, but when I add "/athletes" and try for a POST request, it can't locate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding content-type: 'application/json' header in your POSTMAN request.

Comment: @HunterSeeker thanks, that helped with sending the request! It threw up an error saying invalid JSON, however.

Comment: See if your JSON is correct, also check if you are using the express body parser middleware which parses JSON into req object.
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: @HunterSeeker Thanks. I am using the express body-parser middleware. My JSON is just one variable, so I believe it's correct. I'm sorry for my inexperience/lack of knowledge.

Comment: JSON is a data-interchange format. You need to make sure the JSON you are sending is in the right format. There are tools available to verify if your JSON is correct. Check out http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks @HunterSeeker, it was getting an error so I thought I would read up mongoose and see where I went wrong. Still having some issues, but thanks for your help!